# Как определяется каталог поиска файла?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть такой код:

```
if(File.Exists("text.txt")) //работа с файлом
```

Вопрос в следующем: как определяется каталог в котором будет производится поиск указанного файла?

Как спровоцировать ситуацию, когда файл существует ( в случае с данным примером в каталоге откуда было запущено приложение ) но условие не выполнится?

Comment: Environment.CurrentDirectory; вернет путь до вашего приложения, и File.Exists будет искать там же

Comment: @NMD: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, времени не было на красивое оформление(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если указан относительный путь к файлу, то поиск будет проходить относительно *текущего каталога*. (Получить или изменить его можно при помощи `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.)

Обычно при запуске программы текущий каталог наследуется от запускающей программы*. Это значит, что если вы запустите программу из командной строки, находясь в каталоге с программой, то текущий каталог программы будет совпадать с каталогом, где она расположена. Если вы запустите программу из другого каталога (всё равно, по относительному или по полному пути), каталог программы и её текущий каталог будут отличаться.

Также вы можете установить произвольный рабочий каталог через ярлык:

[image: гуи-гуишечки]

Ну и программа сама может поменять свой рабочий каталог в любой момент через уже упомянутое свойство `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

---

*Если в параметрах функции [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) не указан необязательный параметр `lpCurrentDirectory`. Ну или для C# если в `ProcessStartInfo` не установлено свойство [`WorkingDirectory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WorkingDirectory).

Comment: Спасибо за "lpCurrentDirectory". Только хотел вопрос задавать хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Пожалуйста :)